# Necessary and sufficient condition for separation of variables to give all solutions.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Lets say we have a partial differential with derivatives of $y$ with respect to $x$ and $t$ is there a necessary and sufficient condition that must be obeyed by such an equation for the superposition of the solutions found by separation of variables to give the most general solution? If there is one, I think it may have something to do with Sturm-Liouville equations but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

For linear PDE, the PDE can find the most general solution by separation of variables if the homogeneous part of the PDE can rewrite to the form $\dfrac{\sum\limits_{a_1=0}^{b_1}M_{a_1}(x)X^{[a_1]}(x)}{\sum\limits_{a_2=0}^{b_2}N_{a_2}(x)X^{[a_2]}(x)}=\dfrac{\sum\limits_{a_3=0}^{b_3}P_{a_3}(t)T^{[a_3]}(t)}{\sum\limits_{a_4=0}^{b_4}Q_{a_4}(t)T^{[a_4]}(t)}$ when letting $y(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$ .

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, do you have a source for this?